# How to move a stuck 400m cargo ship?

Tags: ships

I am definitely not the captain of the Evergreen what is currently stuck in the Suez Canal: https://www.google.com/search?q=Evergreen+Suez+Canal

But from an engineering point of view, what would be the best method to move this cargo ship, back to work when it is stuck in the sand.

ex.: highering the canals water level or pulling it with near other cargo ships?

Thanks.

Comment: We understand your interest in this current Charlie Foxtrot, but rescuing grounded ships is pretty much an art form, and every situation (land material, ship mass, hull type,...) is essentially unique.

Comment: https://www.wired.co.uk/article/suez-canal-ship-stuck-ever-given

Comment: And "best method" needs to be defined in terms of safety, cost, speed, etc.

Comment: It's not the first.  It is the biggest.  Lots of tugs, excavators and high tide.

Comment: There is a nice article at BBC on what they are trying https://www.bbc.com/news/56523659

Comment: "what would be the best method to move this cargo ship" Employ a Dutch salvage team. (They are, as noted in the BBC article.)

Comment: In the specific situation ever given, I managed to ever gleen that the efforts are in geared toward freeing the bow by various means - this is better than focusing on freeing the stern since the ships own power might be able to contribute to freeing its stern after the bow is free.